# yup fields required only if other fields are filled in

Tags: formik, yup

I use Yup for my Formik form validation.

I have the following contact form :

```
 const contactForm =
   {
    title: undefined,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: props.contact?.name,
    contactGroup: {
      phone: props.contact?.phone || '',
      email: props.contact?.email || '',
    },
  };
```

when I fill in the fields I would like the lastName field to go to error only when one of the other fields is filled in.

Here is the validation scheme I use to handle form errors

```
 const schema = yup
.object()
.shape<any>({
  firstName: yup.string().max(256, 'max-length'),
  lastName: yup.string().when(['email', 'phone', 'firstName'], {
    is: (email: any, phone: any, firstName: any) =>
      email && phone && firstName,
    then: yup.string().required('empty').max(256, 'max-length'),
  }),
  contactGroup: yup.object().shape<any>(
    {
      phone: yup.string().when('email', {
        is: (email: any) => !email || email === '',
        then: yup.string().max(256, 'max-length'),
      }),
      email: yup
        .string()
        .nullable(true)
        .when('phone', {
          is: (phone: any) => !phone || phone === '',
          then: yup.string().email('invalid').max(256, 'max-length'),
        }),
    },
    [
      ['phone', 'email'],
      ['email', 'phone'],
    ]
  ),
})
.required();
```

I modified the yup in the following way:

```
lastName: yup.string().when(['email', 'phone', 'firstName'], {
    is: (email: any, phone: any, firstName: any) =>
      email && phone && firstName,
    then: yup.string().required('empty').max(256, 'max-length'),
  }),
```

here I ask if the fields email, phone and firstName are filled in the field lastName is set in error.

It works if I do it only on firstName, but if I add email and phone it doesn't work anymore.

I think it comes from the fact that phone and email are in a contactGroup subobject

Is there a solution for this problem ?

lastName should only go into error when one of the fields phone, email or firstName is filled in.